# How can i import address book as CSV from HTC mobile

Tags: mobile-phones

How can i import address book information as CSV file from HTC mobile.. can anybody help me?

Comment: Do you want to *write* a program that does this, or do you want to *find* a program that does this? In the latter case, you should rather ask this on superuser.com.

Answer (score 0):

[vCard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VCard) format might be more appropriate.